# Angular 17 multiple content projection Error

Tags: angular, angular17

I am learning Angular multiple content projection from new Angular 17 docs.
When I am using example from doc I am getting error:

profile.component.html::

```
<div class="red">
  <ng-content select="profile-header"></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <ng-content select="profile-footer"></ng-content>
</div>
```

In app.component.html::

```
<app-profile>
    <profile-header><h2>Header 1</h2></profile-header>
    <p>This is projected content</p>
</app-profile>
```

I am getting this error::

```
NG8001: 'profile-header' is not a known element:
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: profile-header is not a component. This is way to use multiple content project according to new doc. Check this: https://angular.dev/guide/components/content-projection#multiple-content-placeholders

Comment: @AnkurMishra In that example, I think the selector is an actual component!

Comment: @NarenMurali It is little bit confusion in new doc. Old doc has clear view on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select is the equivalent of javascript query selector ( `[<<attribute name>>]` ) so you can do the attribute selector like so.

app.component.html

```
<app-profile>
    <h2 header>Header 1</h2>
    <p>This is projected content</p>
    <h2 footer>Footer 1</h2>
</app-profile>
```

profile.component.html:

```
<div class="red">
  <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="green">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

[docs here](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)

Comment: This is working in 17 as well. Thank you get confused with new angular doc for 17.